# How to make rounded label with an image inside (responsive)

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make an input file with an image. I've got a working solution with div inside the blocked label. File uploads and a rounded preview comes. But this is solved via background. Looks like responsive and I am happy.
But validator told me that it's not proper to put div inside a label tag.
So i tried to put an image tag instead of div.. 
and it doesn't work properly.
http://jsfiddle.net/dkweb/mtsy33k1/9/

```
<div class="photo_container">
<label for="file_photo_id">
<img class="preview" src="http://javascript.ru/img/ws_2.png">
<!--  <img class="preview" src="https://im0-tub-ru.yandex.net/i?id=3b1992e3e1e8d68d24c678ffc749d2f5&n=33&h=170">
       and this doesnt work  -->
</label>
            <input type="file" name="file_photo" id="file_photo_id" />
        </div>
```

- uncomment the sec img and you'll see.
It depends on resolution of the image. I can't hold it a circled always. 
Will you advise on this issue?
They grey area must stay not available for clicking - just a circle with an image inside.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you need to whole picture to be contained out of 2 half circled `img's`?

Comment: how do you want to solve it? should the image be greater in size? or stretched?

Comment: Nope - i change an image for the uploaded one. Just changing a src attribute. I mean - the label should be circled, do not depend on the img attributes inside.. nest an image into the circle)) @robjez - if i understand you comment in a right way - then yes.. line a background-size cover

Comment: Simply uncommenting `img` tag leaves us with 2 images there, so I thought that this might be the case. Your original img is 227 x 170, which will not give you a circle whith `border-radius:50%`. You need square image for that. Why don't you use same logic on `label` element as you used `background image` on `div`? If you were OK with that, nothing stops you from doing same on `label`

Comment: i'try - but the main purpose is... to put a loading gif, while the photo loads.. seems i can't do that via background - it's possible to create a hidden div and fade it in over the label with absolute position so

Comment: label collapses as no content...